# React Native Maps - Make the Marker Callout not overlap other texts in the map

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm making an app using `react-native-maps` and I made a Callout to mimic Google's, as the normal Callout is different. The problem is, as you can see in the image, that the Callout's text is overlapping other texts in the map. How can I guarantee that the Callout's text will avoid that situation? Is it possible with this library?

[image: Example]